# How do I mass rename SonarQube keys to remove the branch part of the key

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to mass **remove** the branch part of the resource key if it exists (':trunk' for instance) of **ALL** projects' and components' keys on a SonarQube instance.

Intial situation :
`groupid1:artifactid1:trunk`
`groupid1:artifactid2:trunk`
...
`groupid1:artifactidN:trunk`
...
`groupidZ:artifactid1:trunk`
`groupidZ:artifactid2:trunk`
...
`groupidZ:artifactidM:trunk`

Expected result :
Intial situation :
`groupid1:artifactid1`
`groupid1:artifactid2`
...
`groupid1:artifactidN`
...
`groupidZ:artifactid1`
`groupidZ:artifactid2`
...
`groupidZ:artifactidM`

What would be the SQL script / web services to use to do this ?

Notes :

- I'm using SonarQube 3.7.4
- I have more than 300 resources keys to modify
- The update key feature available in each project does not the job : i can't replace a string by a blank / empty string.
- The update key feature could be used to do the job on a small set of projects, but as it forces the user to use a non blank string, the only solution is to include the artifactid in the replace string (for instance replace 'artifactid:trunk' by 'artifactid')) which is not viable for 300+ resource keys to be renamed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made the test and the [update key feature](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration#ProjectAdministration-UpdatingProjectKey) perfectly works for your case (may it be on simple or multi-module):

- Replace: `groupid:artifactid:trunk`
- By: `groupid:artifactid`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that's not what i'm asking, i want to remove ":trunk" or ":branchid" from more than 300 keys (including both projects and components). I do not want to have to specify groupid:artifactid for each of them.

Comment: Further, as I wrote I want to do it on ALL projects; with the update key feature I have to do it separately on each project.

Comment: There must be a way to write a SQL script. If I had the columns / tables to update I would be able to write the update script by myself, can you please provide this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, we strongly advise to not touch the DB directly, so we won't provide SQL scripts for that.